# how to close a particular link on click button using javascript?? window.close is closing my current window only

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<h1>Click on the image below to open google homepage </h1>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeFunc()
    {
        window.close();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="google" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <img width="220" height="250" border="0" align="center" src="Wippy Ballons.jpg" alt="image" on>
</a>

<br> <br>

<button onclick="closeFunc()"> Close</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to close the google link which i will open by clicking on image. Using window.close its closing my own tab which has close button. But I want to close the next tab which will open by clicking on image.

Comment: You want to close next all tabs or only next tab?\

Comment: I want to close next tab

Comment: Wait..i am working on it

Comment: Check this:https://jsfiddle.net/h5mDZ/189/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/h5mDZ/191/

js:

```
$("#closeFunc").click(function(e, parameters) { 
 closeFunc();
});
var nextWin;  
$("#google").click(function(e, parameters) {
nextWin=window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
});  
function closeFunc()
{ 
nextWin.close(); 
}
```